Stripe payment issues, I can't store data into database but in stripe dashboard receiving test amount
I have setup the stripe payment system but i am getting Fatal error like this: {Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_f142wGYY4VDGXx) You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1PPNrbGMcptyt0mO8IbOzi1T. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\join\stripe-php\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php on line 38}
I want to to store the stripe payment info from user, but the problem is I am receiving the amount into stripe dashboard but not into my database and getting this fatal errors!
here is my code, and it's started from line 38:
    // set API Key
    $stripe = array(
    "SecretKey"=>"sk_test_51PNnHTGMcptyt0mOGyt8G6VmAvXhlJ7ojBpzdlI1Ey2JLrDghSZ2Nz5UszwSJr9madoDm",
    "PublishableKey"=>"pk_test_51PNnHTGMcptyt0mOSgd8HrIaMr0mj0DM6lyd7W2EqlnzL3L4CHKJ0Yf2EPd9Qid8dOeGXNcwK8j"
    );

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['SecretKey']);

    // Add customer to stripe 
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( 
        'email' => $email, 
        'source'  => $token,
        'name' => $name,
        'description'=>$des
    ));

    // Generate Unique order ID 
    $orderID = strtoupper(str_replace('.','',uniqid('', true)));
     
    // Convert price to cents 
    $itemPrice = ($price*100);
    $currency = "usd";

    // Charge a credit or a debit card 
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 
        'amount'   => $itemPrice, 
        'currency' => $currency, 
        'customer' => $customer->id, 
        'description' => $des
    ));

Anyone can able to solve and tell me where is the problem in this code?
Thank you!

Probably don't want to post your secret key to the Internet...

maybe there are somethings duplicated with 'source'  => $token. I see source is Deprecated so can you try to remove it (link)[https://docs.stripe.com/api/sources]

Like what the error mentions, have you already used the token? One possibility is that you have already attached the token to a customer previously i.e. A token can only be attached to a customer once.
You can try looking through the logs in your Stripe Dashboard if you can't recall whether you did so : https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs
Charges and Tokens are legacy Stripe APIs, you really shouldn't be using them at this point. You'll want to look into  PaymentMethods / PaymentIntents instead. You' can a look at these guides :

https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/quickstart

For how to save a PaymentMethod for future usage :

https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-during-payment
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse

